# Interval for Lagrange remainder in Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a question about Taylor series with Lagrange remainder.
In my example I have point $x_1 = x_0 + \frac{3h}{4}$ where h is constant. Now, it is asked to write function $y(x_0+h)$ in Taylor series with Lagrange remainder using point $x_1$ where remainder is of order 2(second derivative). Here is the solution:
$$y(x_0+h) = y(x_1+\frac{h}{4}) = y(x_1)+y'(x_1)\frac{h}{4}+\frac{y''(\alpha)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{16}$$
This is get using that $x_0 = x_1-\frac{3h}{4}$. Now, in solution it is also written that $\alpha\in(x_0,x_0+h)$ and that is part I don't understand. Using formula for Lagrange remainder $\alpha$ should belong to $(x_1,x_1+\frac{h}{4})$ or in terms of $x_0$ $(x_0+\frac{3h}{4},x_0+h)$. So, my right bound of interval is same as in the solution, but I don't understand why they set left bound to $x_0$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Anyway, if $h>0$ then
$$\alpha\in(x_1,x_1+\frac{h}{4})=(x_0+\frac{3h}{4},x_0+h)\subset (x_0,x_0+h)$$
so, it is also true that $\alpha$ belongs to the interval $(x_0,x_0+h)$.